# Accessing different types of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with few rows. Each rows has header, data and hidden field. Data column can have either text or textarea.

```
<table id="knowledgeTreeTable" class="custom">
<tbody>
  ....................
  <tr>
     <th class="">What is the name of the party?</th>
     <td class="">
        <textarea id="ktField_7" class="ktEdit" type="text"></textarea>
     </td>
     <input id="ktField_7H" type="hidden" value="Unique contested">
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <th class="">What is the name of the opposing party?</th>
     <td class="">
        <input id="ktField_8" class="ktEdit" type="text" style="width: 97%;">
     </td>
     <input id="ktField_8H" type="hidden" value="Query">
  </tr>
  ......................
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am able to read the content of header and hidden field but not sure how to read data column as it can have two different types of element.

```
$("#knowledgeTreeTable tr").each(function() {
        alert($('th', this).text());//OK
        //alert($('td > [input, textarea]', this).val()); // This is not OK.
        alert($('input', this).val());//OK
    });
```

Comment: `alert($('input,textarea', this).val());`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: only `<th>` and `<td>` elements are valid children of `<tr>` elements; even if you can't see a hidden `<input>` it's still their. Still messing up your HTML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you would in a CSS selector, look for *both*:

```
alert($('td > input, td > textarea', this).val());
```

Although since you're using the same class for both, I'd be inclined to use:

```
alert($('td > .ktEdit', this).val());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't group selectors like

```css
td > [input, textarea]
```

Instead, use

```css
td > input, td > textarea
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're trying to access a child element in a loop like this, you need to establish what the common factors between each element is. In this case they are different tags with different names, but they both have the ktEdit class, and both have `type="text"` (which I don't believe is actually applicable to textareas).

In this case, the common variable is the class name, so you can use that as your selector. As long as you target your parent loop correctly, it won't matter if you use that class on other elements throughout the page:

```
$("#knowledgeTreeTable tr").each(function() {
    alert($('.ktEdit', this).val());
});
```